# Login remotely to Drupal 7 site using services module

Tags: api, drupal, service

**GOAL:**

I want my web app to be able to send username and password of a user on my Drupal site, to the Drupal site and have the Drupal site respond with confirmation of whether the user authentication information is correct.

Another need is to have the Drupal server return a session id for a session created, and information for the user, like email, user role, etc.

**What I have so far:**

I've enabled Services Rest Server, and created an endpoint at www.mysite.com/rest/.  I've set the response format to json only, and request parser to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I've turned on authentication by session, debugging mode.  I've also made sure to enable the entire user resource for this endpoint.  Navigating to www.mysite.com/rest/user does give me a list of all users.

Regarding my attempts with authentication, I've tried sending requests:

```
POST www.mysite.com/rest/user/login
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    POST Body:
        name:admin,
        pass:myadminpassword
```

But it just keeps returning a 401 Unauthorized response.  I've double checked and the auth information is correct. I've tried other variations on parameter names like: (username, password), (user, pass), (name, password), etc.

I can't seem to get the login to work and I've looked through other examples I've found on Stackoverflow but they haven't worked.

Comment: Shouldn't the body be: "username=admin&password=adminpass" if you are using "x-www-form-urlencoded"?

Comment: aaaaaaaand of course it was something so simple.  I forgot that POST parameters and GET parameters are formatted the same way.  Thank you.

Comment: you can also POST in json (or any other format that's supported by the service module). Just click the checkbox on the "server" tab of your service resource config and fill the body of your POST with a json object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is good documentation for the services module in drupal.org. Particulary there are several examples for using servicers here: http://drupal.org/node/783722

The example on this page is using command line tool curl: http://drupal.org/node/1795770

And contains one example for login:

```
curl -X POST -i -H "Content-type: application/json" -c cookies.txt -X POST http://localhost:8888/service/user/login -d '
{
    "username":"user",
    "password":"password"
}
'
```

So:

- you have your endpoint ok
- Content-type should be application/json
- and the body should be something like { "username":"admin", "password":"pass" }