# Login Prompt is Lost in Drupal. So is there a way to by pass it?

Tags: drupal

I am having some issues with my Drupal 7.

Because of a different bug I am having with component or panel, one that is taking over pages and hiding other parts of a page somehow, my login page has been corrupted.

what is supposed to be my /user and/or user/login page looks completely as it should not look.  The username and password prompt and input fields are missing because of a component which needs to be removed.  This component has somehow managed to cover or hide the thing I need.

The bug that has caused this problem is beyond the scope of this post but I believe that it is probably a requirement to log into the admin panel in order to fix the issue.

How do I log in if I can not get the login prompt page to come up as it should?

Answer (score 0):

**drush**

You can request a one time login link for any user account using the drush command [`user-login`](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/user/user-login/) :

```
drush user-login <uid|username|email>
```

It's aliased `uli` and  default to 1 (admin), the following has probably saved millions of drupal devs ;) :

```
drush uli
```

---

**Services module**

You can also login "RESTFully" via cURL or equivalent by submitting a POST request to the appropriated endpoint without loading the form. You just need the [services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module.

[Login remotely to Drupal 7 site using services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962259/login-remotely-to-drupal-7-site-using-services-module)
[Authenticated Request with cURL](https://drupalize.me/videos/making-authenticated-requests-curl?p=1487)

Comment: This looks good.  I will ask my internet service provider to do this since I am not hosting the site locally.